Moksha - Who all are eligible to get moksha
The concept of Moksha:
Does it apply to all the jivas on earth such as insects, animals, birds, humans, etc.
Or does it apply only to humans?
I am not asking whether other non-human jivas are capable of getting moksha or not. Whether they are capable or not is a separate thing. Only humans have the capacity to achieve moksha and animals in highly rarely exceptional cases.
But my question is, does the concept of moksha apply to all jivas?
Are all jivas entitled to get moksha from samsara? Or is it just applicable for humans alone?

You might find this question to be of interest. Welcome to HSE!

Who get moksha will depend on the philosophy you follow which can't be generalized.

Advaida Vedāntam says moksha is for souls (jiva/जिव) to identify with brahman (ब्रह्मन्) and becomes one. This implies that brahman alone exists nothing else.
Vishishtādvaita Vedāntam says that moksha is for souls (jiva/जिव) to reach the abode of Lord Narayana and stay with Him for ever. Jivas will look like Lord Narayana but never transcend or equal to him.
Dvaita Vedāntam says that moksha is for souls (jiva/जिव), who are Mukti-yogyas (मुक्ति-योग्य/Eligible for mukti) among three different classes of souls(Jīvas), to reach the abode of Lord Narayana and stay with Him for ever, however, Jivas will always be inferior to Lord Narayana.


Beware: The other two types of souls (Jīvas), who are Nitya-samsārins (नित्य-संसारिन्) and Tamo-yogyas (तमोयोग्य)
respectively, will never attain moksha!


Yoga darshana says Moksha is isolation (Kaivalya/कैवल्य). i.e. isolation of purusha from prakṛti. Since both are real, while purusha isolates itself from prakirit, after realization, the result is both are isolated. So who gets moksha?

I) Your first question The concept of Moksha(liberation) does it apply to all the jivas on earth such as insects, animals birds humans etc Or It applies only to humans alone?
That depends upon the philosophy you follow. Ādhi Sankarāchārya(Advaidam) and Ramānujāchārya(Vishishtādvaitam) both agree moksha is for all Jīvātmans irrespective of human and non-human.
According to Madhvāchārya(Dvaitam), there are differences between the liberated Jīvas, i.e., liberated Jīvas are not only not equal to God but also not equal to each other. There are Nitya-samsārins (नित्य-संसारिन्) and Tamo-yogyas (तमोयोग्य) who will never attain moksha! So animals that fall in the category of Mukti-yogyas only are eligible for Moksha. e-g Lord Sri Hanuman(Vānara) and Lord Sri Jāmbavān(King of Bears).
II) Your second question I am not asking whether other non-human jivas are capable of getting moksha or not Whether they capable or not is a seperate thing . Only humans have the capacity to achieve moksha and animals in highly rarely exceptional cases.
That depends upon the philosophy you follow. Refer answer to your 1st question.
III) Your third and final question But my question is does the concept of moksha apply to all jivas ? Are all jivas entitled to get moksha from samsara? Or its just applicable for humans alone Please kindly answer me someone.
That depends upon the philosophy you follow. Refer answer to your 1st question.
Conclusion:
Moksha is not a general thing applicable homogeneously. Firstly, you have to express your philosophical stand point such as Advaida, Vishishtādvaita, Dvaita  and Yoga darshana because the concept of Moksha varies from philosophy to philosophy.

Also, one more question i read somewhere called Nithya-badda and nithya-siddha . Are they same as Nithya samsarins? I have one question here, there are so many devotees of God who worship God do chanting naam jap practice  bhakti yoga with throughout their life but not qualified enough to be called Nithya -siddha . They fall between Nithya-badha and Nithya-siddha. That means even though they are devotees of god, still they are eternally cursed to stay in samsar and never get liberation at all even though they are devotees of god .

Sir, can you please answer this question of mine as well. Would be really greatful. Thanks a lot in advance https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61326/vaishnava-madhva-nithya-badda-and-nithya-siddha-and-tamo-yogya

So all of their philosophy are contradictory to each other regarding moksha is applicable to whom because as per Advaita and Vishishtadvaita, moksha is applicable for every Jiva as u said but as per dvaita there is high restrictions. If there is a law of nature , only one reality can exist. As all the above are contradictory . So which actually is the law of nature and which is not ? Because  two or more contradictory realities cannot exist together in reality right

@Karthik, Let us not take it as contradictory but understand each philosophy’s point of view. You will have look into from evolution point of view. From Dvaita Vedāntam to Vishishtādvaita Vedāntam and finally to Advaida Vedāntam. To reach the  highest rung (Advaidam) one has to climb from lowest rung which is Dvaitam. These philosophies have been laid down by great āchāryās, so let us try to understand them with reverence rather than as contradictions. Without understanding those differences in philosophies, we will never get clarity.

QUESTION: Does the concept of moksha apply to all jivas? Are all jivas entitled to get moksha from samsara? Or is it just applicable for humans alone?
Only humans can attain  moksha.
Evolution of the creatures

They are controlled by virtues and vices in the form of bliss and
sorrow. Their bodies have different castes, age and enjoyment born of
their different karmas.
Then again in every birth, o bird, they obtain subtle bodies and after
attaining moksha they acquire indestructible fame.
The departed souls enter into insentient objects, worms, birds,
animals, men, deities, but after release do not enter into any object
or anybody at all.
Passing through four types of bodies in order of their karmas and
leaving one body after the other a thousand times, taking birth in
human form, and acquiring knowledge due to good acts one obtains
release.

[Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda, Chapter XLIX]
Number of births and importance of human birth

In the eighty four lacs of bodies of creatures one does not acquire
true knowledge anywhere unless one is born as a man.
Here, after thousands of crores of births a creature obtains human
form only sometime due to aggregate of virtue.
Having obtained a rare human form he should endeavour for moksha. If
he does not endeavor for it, there can be no greater sinner in the
world.
Born in the most beautiful human form he incurs the sin of slaying a
Brahmin if he neglects his self.
Without human body it is not possible to obtain the supreme goal. One
should be, therefore, very cautious to guard wealth in the form of his
body and perform good actions. ……
So far as this body remains intact
he should practice dharma. One is a perfect fool who digs a well only
when the house is on fire.

[Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda, Chapter XLIX]

Abhinavagupta in his Gita commentary 9.32 says even animals can attain moksha, your comments on that

Moksha is for those who can distinguish between good and bad acts. Can animals do that?

It's mentioned in preta khanda chapter 46, That a jiva gets human birth once Paap and Punya are equalized . And at last they say after thousands of crores of births very rare one gets human birth. Are both contradictory or same ?
