Vaishnava / Madhva Nithya badda and Nithya siddha and Tamo Yogya
Namasthe .
I have one question.
I read somewhere that there is concept of Nithya baddha and Nithya Siddha and nitya samsarins and also Tamo yogyas created by Madhva and Vaishnava scholars
They say Nithya-siddha is someone who has got moksha
Nithya-badda and Nithya - samsarins are those who are exterally  in samsara and never get moksha
If we see in today's world , there are thousands of devotees of god who worship God do naam Jap chanting practice  bhakti Yoga etc?
They are not Nithya-samsarins(or Nithya baddhaa) who are completely into samsara as they are devotees and they are not qualified to be called  Nithya-siddha as well because they are not perfected siddhas
Because not everyone who worship God or chant are siddhas
So these kind of people I am talking about are devotees of God who practice Bhakti yoga but they fall between Nithya-samsarins(or Nithya badda) and Nithya siddha, not completely Nithya-badda not completely Nithya-siddha
What about the fate of such devotees? Will they never get Moksha and permanently eternally bound to samsara even if they are devotees of god and worship God , and follow Bhakti Yoga
I sincerely request if anyone can please clarify my question.
Also, one more question I had,
There is one more sect called Tamo-Yogya. Not everyone are born as humans in immediate next life even if they are devotees of god . So suppose if a devotee of God gets a non-human life such as animals or birds just for one or two lives accidentally, does it mean they will never get moksha because as they entered animals kingdom they fall under Tamo-Yogyas and unfit for liberation even if they are devotees of god ?. So in that case if they are devotees of god , will they never get moksha or chance to enter spiritual abode of Ishvara just because they accidentally got animal life or just one or two lives may be?

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 9, Verse 31
क्षिप्रं भवति धर्मात्मा शश्वच्छान्तिं निगच्छति | कौन्तेय प्रतिजानीहि न मे भक्त: प्रणश्यति || 31||
TRANSLATION
He quickly becomes righteous and attains lasting peace. O son of
Kuntī, declare it boldly that My devotee never perishes.

Here Krishna says My devotee never perishes . Does it apply to such devotees who are stuck between nithya-badda and Nithya-siddha or accidentally born animals for one life suddenly if they fall under tamo-yogyas as I explained earlier. Does this sloka be of any use here ? I mean can these type of devotees never get moksha and eternally stuck in samsara even if they are devotees just because they accidentally fall into animal kingdom for one or two lives or stuck between Nithya badda and Nithya siddha?
Please kindly explain in detail
Thanks in advance
Regards

your answer lies BG. 16 there are only 2 types suri and assuri .. demonic people even if they do extreme austerities based on the soul nature they will defenitely reach andhan tamas. Even if one is suri (non demonic character)  they take animal birth like worm he will attain moksha because his nature of soul is pure. mahabharat vedvyas delivers one worm from its birth and reach ultimately moksha there were several reference to this in BG itself.

Pardon me i didn't understand what is meant by andhan tamas sir ?

Andha - Dark Tamas - sorrowful (dark and sarrowful place for jivas is mother womb)

I) Your first question I have one question. I read somewhere that there is concept of Nithya baddha and Nithya Siddha and nitya samsarins and also Tamo yogyas created by Madhva and Vaishnava scholars
Bhaktivedanta Swami Srila Prabhupada who founded ISKCON teaches two kinds of living entities:

nitya-siddha
nitya-baddha

Nitya-siddha means they never fall a victim of māyā contrarily the one who is victimized is called nitya-baddha.
Unlike nitya-baddha, even though Nitya-siddha are within this material world, they are never victimized at hands of māyā.
So the Kṛiṣṇa consciousness movement is to make the nitya-baddhas again nitya-siddha, that is to bring them back. Prabhupada opiniate that it is a difficult task because  nitya-baddha are like a madman. A madman, to again bring him to the normal life is very difficult task.

Whereas Nitya samsarins and also Tamo yogyas are entities of Dvaita
Vedāntam who will never attain moksha!

II) Your second question They say Nithya-siddha is someone who has got moksha.
Yes, they eligible for moksha, in according to Prabhupada.
III) Your third question Nithya-badda and Nithya - samsarins are those who are exterally in samsara and never get moksha.
Answer is Yes.
IV) Your fourth question If we see in today's world , there are thousands of devotees of god who worship God do naam Jap chanting practice bhakti Yoga etc? They are not Nithya-samsarins(or Nithya baddhaa) who are completely into samsara as they are devotees and they are not qualified to be called Nithya-siddha as well because they are not perfected siddhas Because not everyone who worship God or chant are siddhas.
Prabhupada says Nitya-siddha are very much within this material world, however they are never victimized at hands of māyā.
At the same time Prabhupada introduces grades which are Nitya-siddha, sādhana-siddha and kṛpā-siddha. By devotion one can become sādhana-siddha.

By following the rules and regulations and instructions of the spiritual master, he can also become Nitya-siddha.

V) Your fifth question So these kind of people I am talking about are devotees of God who practice Bhakti yoga but they fall between Nithya-samsarins(or Nithya badda) and Nithya siddha……….I sincerely request if anyone can please clarify my question.
So the Kṛiṣṇa consciousness movement is to make the nitya-baddhas again nitya-siddha, that is to bring them back. Prabhupada says that it is a difficult task because nitya-baddha are like a madman. A madman, to again bring him to the normal life is very difficult task.
VI) Your sixth question Also, one more question I had, There is one more sect called Tamo-Yogya. Not everyone are born as humans in immediate next life ……..they accidentally got animal life or just one or two lives may be?
Madhvāchārya clears states that Tamo-yogyas will never reach moksha. Due to the Sanchita Karma, if a devotee assumes an animal form, then you can’t simply brand him as Tamo-yogyas because he may assume again human form in the forthcoming birth!

So, don’t brand all animal forms as Tamo-yogyas and vice versa.
If so, then both Lord Hanuman and Lord Jāmbavān being in animal form will never be eligible for moksha which is absurd.

VII) Your seventh and final question Here Krishna says My devotee never perishes . Does it apply to such devotees who are stuck between nithya-badda and Nithya-siddha or accidentally born animals for one life suddenly if they fall under tamo-yogyas as I explained earlier. Does this sloka be of any use here ? I mean can these type of devotees never get moksha and eternally stuck in samsara even if they are devotees just because they accidentally fall into animal kingdom for one or two lives or stuck between Nithya badda and Nithya siddha?
From the Dvaita Vedāntam point of view, Devotee means Mukti-yogyas (मुक्ति-योग्य/Eligible for mukti) alone. Even Mukti-yogyas can assume animal form due to Sanchita Karma, but they will not lose their eligibility for moksha because they will assume human form any time again in forthcoming births. This is what Lord Krishna says [Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 9, Verse 31] that My devotee never perishes.
Conclusion:

Don’t assume all animal births are Tamo-yogyas and vice versa.


Thanks for the explanation. Are sadhana siddhas eligible for moksha sir ? If someone is doing regular worship of God with devotion  , chanting etc are they come under sadhana-siddha ? Are sadhana siddhas eligible for moksha ?

@Karthik, Even though Prabhupada compares Nithya badda to a madman, but he has not given them up. Prabhupada says that as descirbed in “Nectar of Devotion”, one can become Sādhana-siddha. By following the rules and regulations and instructions of the spiritual master, he can also become siddha and then again become nitya-siddha.

Thanks for answering sir. I just needed to ask for a clarification regarding something. Could you please kindly answer this sir. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61328/can-devotees-be-saved-from-destruction-such-as-durgati-or-adhogati Thanks a lot for your inputs. Really helpful .

I have one question . As Srila Prabhupada says Krishna consciousness movement is to make Nithya baddhas to Nithya siddhas and he says Nithya siddha is required to get moksha. So if a devotee who is sadhana siddha if suppose assume some demi-god cursed him to become animals forever , will Krishna uplift them to get human birth as they are devotees of krishna and come under sadhana-siddha so that they can spirituality progress towards becoming Nithya siddha? Please kindly answer me

@Karthik, Though Prabhupāda is a follower of Dvaida Vendānta, but he deviates from Madhvāchāryā as far as Nitya-samsārins and Tamo-yogyās are concerned. That is, Prabhupāda replaces them with Nitya-baddha comparing with a madman who are very difficult to convert to nitya-siddha but never said that they are impossible to convert.

@Karthik, Suppose some higher force curses a sādhana siddha to be an animal forever (even though it is very very rare to occur), he has to undergo with such curse as a result of his Prārabdha karma. Lord Krishna can’t interfere with a curse because curse is a curse! Nevertheless, Lord Krishna is capable of either modifying or offering Śāpa-Vimocana (शाप-विमोचन/Relief from Curse) to the curse, if victim’s karma is so. All depends on victim’s Karma alone and no God can interfere because God (or Lord Krishna for that matter) is merely a witness to all our activities and the Karma we earned!

The Svetāsvatara upanishad (श्वेताश्वतर उपनिषद्) says Supreme Purusha is in this body as the witness: एको देवः सर्वभूतेषु गूढःसर्वव्यापी सर्वभूतान्तरात्मा। कर्माध्यक्षः सर्वभूताधिवासः साक्षी चेता केवलो निर्गुणश्च ॥ ६:११॥ eko devaḥ sarvabhūteṣu gūḍhaḥ sarvavyāpī sarvabhūtāntarātmā karmādhyakṣaḥ sarvabhūtādhivāsaḥ sākṣī cetā kevalo nirguṇaś ca ॥ 6.11 ॥ The non-dual and resplendent Lord is hidden in all beings. All-pervading, the inmost Self of all creatures, the impeller to actions, abiding in all things, He is the Witness [sākṣī], the Animator and the Absolute, free from gunas.

Bhagvad Gita corroborates Svetāsvatara upanishad that God is witness as follows [13.23]:
उपद्रष्टानुमन्ता च भर्ता भोक्ता महेश्वर: |
परमात्मेति चाप्युक्तो देहेऽस्मिन्पुरुष: पर: || 23||
upadrashtaanumantaa cha bhartaa bhoktaa maheshwarah
paramaatmeti chaapyukto dehe'smin purushah parah ॥ 13.23 ॥
Meaning: The Supreme Purusha in this body is also called the Witness [upadraṣhṭā], the Approver, the Supporter, the Experiencer, the Sovereign Lord and the Supreme Self.

God will never favour this nor that, so God stands without prejudice. To support this view more concretely, there is saying in Tamil:
அரசன் அன்று கொல்வான், தெய்வம் நின்று கொல்லும்.
Arasan andru kolvaan, Deivam Nindru Kollum.
Meaning: King will decide the death [punishment] on the same day and may be instantly but God will give long rope to teach us [through Karma] the lesson.

Suppose if the person has not done any such huge sin to deserve that, if someone curse them that they become animal bird forever as long as god exists for eternity. If they have not done any such huge karma in sanchita karma or prarabdha karma to deserve that? Will krishna and intervene and protect devotee in this case or just leave it and let the devotee perish forever even if he has not done any such sin to deserve such a huge  curse of punishment

Sir actually my question was. Nithya-badda are not eligible for Moksha right. But if someone has becomr sadhana-siddha through sadhana and following the principles of Bhakti yoga and does Chanting , Parayan, Naam jap, puja , worship and devotional service to God ? Will they come under sadhana siddha ? Are sadhana siddha eligible for moksha or not ?

Namasthe sir. Sorry if I am bothering you. I just wanted to ask this one last question. It's really important for me please can you answer this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/61359/44150

@Karthik, your question asked in the link was just now answered. Good Luck!

Sir , you didn't answer this part. If I break any promises like if I eat junk food my father will rot in lower Yonis for eternity. Here u mentioned eating robbed money there is a connection. In case suppose if there is no connection of any sort because of my OCD promises will it affect my family if i break my OCD promises. For example if I touch this wooden door , my mother will rot in hell for one kalpa will it affect them? –
Karthik

@Karthik, My answer to your question has been added up in post. Good Luck! https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61359/breaking-promises-do-our-loved-ones-ancestors-rot-in-hell-and-or-suffer-if-we-b/61367#61367

Thanks sir. One last question i have. If there is a devotee of God who is sadhana siddha. Does concept of moksha apply to sadhana siddha?

@Karthik, Sādhana-siddha is an intermediate stage between Nithya baddha and Nithya Siddha. Prabhupada says that by following the rules and regulations and instructions of the spiritual master, Sādhana-siddha will be elevated to siddha and then finally become nitya-siddha. Therefore, it is guaranteed that sadhana siddha is very much eligible for moksha.
