Can Devotees be saved from Destruction such as Durgati or Adhogati?
Namasthe to All,
I have one question
In Spirituality, is Durgati and Adhogati same as perishing(or destruction) in Spiritual context?
There is one slokam from Bhagavad Gita

BHAGAVAD GITA CHAPTER 9 VERSE 31
Bg. 9.31 क्षिप्रं भवति धर्मात्मा शश्वच्छान्तिं निगच्छति । कौन्तेय प्रतिजानीहि न मे भक्त: प्रणश्यति ॥ ३१ ॥
TRANSLATION
He quickly becomes righteous and attains lasting peace. O son of Kuntī, declare it boldly that My devotee never
perishes.

I will give one hypothetical example
Note :- This is a sincere request. Please kindly assume this for the question POV. Please don't reply that its not real and cannot happen in reality. It's completely hypothetical and it cannot happen in reality I know. My only intention is to ask if this verse from Gita applies to such kind of situation or not. Please assume the scenario and answer me accordingly .
My intention of asking this is to check if this part Naa Mei Bhakta Pranshyati of the above sloka applies to such scenario or not
Suppose if there came a situation where someone out of envy cursed a devotee of God that let him become animal for eternity means let him never get a human birth again not even in trillions of Kalpas means let him not get a human life for eternity
Here assume that the person has not done such bad karma to deserve it
Here as per the above mentioned sloka from Bhagavad Gita , Krishna says to Arjuna that his devotee never perishes .

Naa mei bhakta pranshyati

So in this context, a person getting lower yoni (Adhogati) for eternity is considered as destruction or perish in spiritual context?
Does Adhogati refer to transmigration into lower realms or lower species ?
So, if we assume that person has not done any such grave sins to deserve that if he does not have such huge baggage of bad karma and has done lot of punya and virtues in this life and if he is a devotee of God who regularly worships God, chanting , Sadhana Nam Jaap and engaged in devotional service to God
Please kindly answer me if that sloka applies to save such a person from eternally going to lower yoni as per this curse and get him human birth ?
Please also state if there is any such scriptures which state regarding the same  topic or context from any authentic scriptures?
Please do answer and clarify my query
Would be very great full
Thanks a lot in advance

This is my understanding. It is impossible for anyone (any jeeva) to curse someone for eternity because taposhakti cannot be infinite. Any curse needs taposhakti to take effect. No jeeva, however exalted, will have infinite taposhakti.

@estimator, please assume there is a hypothetical situation its not real and cannot happen in reality. It's completely hypothetical and it cannot happen in reality I know. My only intention is to ask if this verse from Gita will apply or not. This verse Naa mei bhakta pranshyati, when Krishna says my devotee never perishes, can it save that person from adhogati (or rotting in lower Yonis) and get them a human birth?

Yes, Bhagavan is higher than any jeeva, however powerful the jeeva may be. Bhagavan's words are superior to any curse by a jeeva. So Bhagavan Krishna's words can save His sincere devotees.

So as per above sloka, when he says Naa mei bhakta pranshyati , does it imply God protects his devotees from spiritual destruction such as in this case can god protect his devotees from eternally rotting in lower species and get a human birth ? Sorry for asking again i just wanted to clarify this. Please do answer me Thanks

Yes, Bhagavan protects devotees from spiritual destruction.

The scriptural source for adhogati is Gita 16.6-20. I am posting two of these verses.

These vicious men, oppressive, cruel and sinful as they are, - are
always hurled down by Me into demoniac wombs in life after life, in
the transmigratory cycle.

Gita 16.19

O son of Kunti! Falling into demoniac wombs, in life after life, they
go to still lower states of degradation, without attaining Me.

Gita 16.20
What is the implication of these Gita verses?

In these verses and those preceding them, a theory of two types of
souls with inherently opposite tendencies seems to be propounded.
Vivid description of both these types is given in verses 1 to 5 and 7
to 20. One type called Daivi or divine, is Godward-looking and is
receptive to ideas leading to liberation from the clutches of Prakrti.
The other type called Asuri is just the opposite. Those who are
included in it are steeped in worldliness and are anti-God and
anti-spiritual. According to the theory propounded here, the former
gradually evolve their higher faculties, and attain liberation from
Prakrti, while the latter become eternally involved in Samsara. It is
also said in verse 20 that they are repeatedly born in 'devilish
wombs' (asurim yonim) and without taking the Godward path, attain to
adhamam gatim - 'the most heinous destiny'.
On the basis of such texts, some schools of Vedanta like those of Sri
Madhva and Sri Vallabha have propounded the theory of taratamya or
inherent qualitative differences in Jivas, some being made for
salvation and others for degradation. There is no eternal damnation in
Hinduism, but this confinement to 'adhamam gatim' or continued
embodiments among the lowest creatures like insects, fish, snakes
etc., corresponds to it as the wages for confirmed evil doers.
There is a theoretical possibility of salvation even for such degraded
souls when Divine grace descends on them through Incarnations and
through very holy saints. Since Samsara or the transmigratory cycle is
a never-ending process, perpetual involvement in it is the attaining
to that most heinous destiny - yanti-adhamam-gatim.

Commentary on Gita 16.6-20 by Swami Tapasyananda
Question: In Spirituality, is Durgati and Adhogati same as perishing(or destruction) in Spiritual context?
Answer: Swami Tapasyananda thinks adhogati means birth as lowest creatures like insects.
Question: Suppose if there came a situation where someone out of envy cursed a devotee of God that let him become animal for eternity means let him never get a human birth again not even in trillions of Kalpas means let him not get a human life for eternity
.........................
So in this context, a person getting lower yoni (Adhogati) for eternity is considered as destruction or perish in spiritual context?
Answer: It is impossible for someone's curse to turn any person into an animal for eternity since it violates the theory of Karma.
Question: Does Adhogati refer to transmigration into lower realms or lower species ?
Answer: Adhogati means birth in lower species.
Question:Please kindly answer me if that sloka (9.31) applies to save such a person from eternally going to lower yoni as per this curse and get him human birth ?
Answer: Gita 9.31 is of course an assurance. There is an explicit assurance in Gita 9.22.

Whoever, being devoted to Me solely, engage themselves always in
contemplation and worship of Me – to such ever-steadfast devotees I
ensure the procurement of all their wants and preservation of their
assets (worldly interests).

Gita 9.22

I) Your first question In Spirituality, is Durgati and Adhogati same as perishing(or destruction) in Spiritual context?
i) Durgati(दुर्गति/துர்க்கதி) means want of , misfortune, poverty, hell.

In spirituality Durgati means hell.

ii) Adhogati(अधोगति/அதோகதி ) means going downwards, descending, going to hell, Descending into an inferior form of existence;

In spirituality Adhogati means taking inferior from of births such as insects, plants, birds, fish and other forms of animals.

II) Your second question There is one slokam from Bhagavad Gita………….So in this context, a person getting lower yoni (Adhogati) for eternity is considered as destruction or perish in spiritual context?
Suppose some higher force curses someone to be born Adhogati(अधोगति/Birth in a Lower Yoni), forever (even though it is very very rare to occur), he has to undergo with such curse as a result of his Prārabdha karma. Lord Krishna can’t interfere with a curse because curse is a curse! Nevertheless, Lord Krishna is capable of either modifying or offering Śāpa-Vimocana (शाप-विमोचन/Relief from Curse) to the curse, if victim’s karma is so. All depends on victim’s Karma alone and no God can interfere because God (or Lord Krishna for that matter) is merely a witness to all our activities and the Karma we earned!

This birth of Adhogati should never be interpreted as destruction or perish in spiritual context because the spiritual progress made so far can’t be undone. When that devotee regains another birth as human, he will resume the process of spiritual advancement from that point onwards.

Bhagavān Krishna says in Bhagavath Geetha [8.6] about regaining the same state at the time of death in a future birth as follows:

यं यं वापि स्मरन्भावं त्यजत्यन्ते कलेवरम् |
तं तमेवैति कौन्तेय सदा तद्भावभावित: || 6||
yam yam vapi smaran bhavam tyajatyante kalevaram
tam tam evaiti kaunteya sada tad-bhava-bhavitah
Whatever one remembers upon giving up the body at the time of death, O son of Kunti, one attains that state, being always absorbed in such contemplation.

Thus, Sri Krishna guarantees that whatever state of being one remembers when he quits his body, that state he will attain without fail.
III) Your third question Does Adhogati refer to transmigration into lower realms or lower species?
Answer is Yes.
IV) Your fourth question So, if we assume that person has not done any such grave sins to deserve that if he does not have such huge baggage of bad karma and has done lot of punya and virtues in this life and if he is a devotee of God who regularly worships God, chanting , Sadhana Nam Jaap and engaged in devotional service to God.
Bhagavān Krishna says in Bhagavath Geetha [8.5] about taking future birth that depends upon your thought at the time of death as given below:

अन्तकाले च मामेव स्मरन्मुक्त्वा कलेवरम् |
य: प्रयाति स मद्भावं याति नास्त्यत्र संशय: || 5||
anta-kāle cha mām eva smaran muktvā kalevaram
yaḥ prayāti sa mad-bhāvaṁ yāti nāstyatra sanśhayaḥ
Those who relinquish the body while remembering Me at the moment of death will come to Me. There is certainly no doubt about this.

If one thinks about a bird at the time of death, then he will assume a bird form in the forthcoming birth [Refer my Quora Post on Jada Bharatha(जडभरत)]. If you utter ‘Govinda’ at the moment of death, you will reach the Padāravinda(पदारविन्द/Lotus Feet) of Lod Krishna! That is, the nature of forthcoming reincarnation entirely rests in your hands or more particularly based on your Karmāsaya(कर्माशय/Latent Impressions of Action) stored in Kārana Sarīra(कारण शरीर/Causal Body/காரண சரீரம்).

Beware: Karmāsaya(कर्माशय), which are the Latent Impressions of Action based on
Klesā(क्लेशा/Affliction/இடுக்கண்/துக்கம்/இடும்பை/உபத்திரவு), forms the
foundation of Punarjanma(पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation). This can also be
viewed in terms of Vedantic parlance as subset of Sanchita
Karma(सञ्चित कर्म/Accumulated) which are ripe and ready to sprout.

Even though a person has done a lot of punya kārya and devotional acts in the present birth as mentioned by you, but at the time of death that person's thought will be totally based on his Prārabdha karma(if it is good he will utter 'Govinda' otherwise he will think about something else that will lead to adhogati) and so, he may end up in lower births.
V) Your fifth question Please kindly answer me if that sloka applies to save such a person from eternally going to lower yoni as per this curse and get him human birth?
Please read my answer for question No. (II).
VI) Your sixth and final question Please also state if there is any such scriptures which state regarding the same topic or context from any authentic scriptures?
To know about Karma and Punarjanma(पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) in details, one has read Patanjali’s Yoga Sutras(योग सूत्र) and its organization thoroughly.
According to Hinduism, it is the Prārabdha Karma (प्रारब्ध कर्म) who is responsible for Punarjanma (पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) of an entity, who is born as a boy or a girl, who is born rich or poor, who is born blind or not, who is born deaf or not, who is born dump or not, who is born brilliant or dull or insane and so on.
You may wonder how does Prārabdha Karma decide the embodiment, the Life-span and the experiences needed for forthcoming reincarnation of an entity? According to Ashtānga Yoga (अष्टाङ्गयोग) authored by Maharishi Patanjali(महऋषि पतञ्जलि), the basis for Punarjanma (पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) is Karmāsaya(कर्माशय/Latent Impressions of Action), also known as Prārabdha Karma in vedānta philosophy, which causes Trivipāka (embodiment/Jāti, longevity/Āyush and experience/Bhoga) for every incarnation of entities. To know about Principles of Karmāsaya(कर्माशय) and Trivipāka please refer my Quora post: Trivipāka(embodiment/Jāti, longevity/Āyush and experience/Bhoga).
Conclusion:
Except Hinduism and Buddhism, other religions believe that cause of births is simply God! If so, then how will you explain births of some who are lame, blind or deaf; born poor or rich; born idiot or bright and so on. If God is the cause, then how did God decide so? Also bear in mind that those Religions refuse Punarjanma (पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) and do not aware of its existence! Therefore, God, described by those Religions, is being with prejudice.
But according to Hinduism God is just a Witness. i.e. He never oversee (or being the cause for) the births and deaths of entities(Human and Non-Human forms). That is it. Keep in mind that it is the Prārabdha Karma that causes them(birth and death)!

Buddhism does not accept existence of God but accept Karma and Samsāra(संस्कार/Cycle of Existence/Cycle of Birth and Death).

According to Hinduism, God, therefore, will never be accused of being with prejudice, because it is the Prārabdha Karma(प्रारब्ध कर्म) who is responsible for Punarjanma(पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) of an entity, who is born as a boy or a girl, who is born rich or poor, who is born blind or not, who is born deaf or not, who is born dump or not, who is born brilliant or dull or insane and so on.
It is the Prārabdha Karma(or Principles of Karmāsaya/कर्माशय) who decides not only the life-span(longevity) but also the embodiment(Jāti/Species) of the present birth such as Humans, Ghosts, Bhūta, Preta, Pisāca, Devatha and Adhogati entities (animals, insects, birds, fishes, trees, plants and so on).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
