Consequences of breaking promise
I have an extremely important question
I am suffering with severe mental health issues such as OCD problem.
I read,
Somewhere it's mentioned in Padma puran that breaking promises affect our ancestors for 7 generations above and 7 generations below?

If the Padma Purana says so then it must be true but a contradicting statement can be found in Smritis, according to which consequences of sins committed by the children have to be suffered by the children alone and not by their ancestors.

9 If any of the children commit sins, they alone perish, like the leaf of a tree. They do not harm their ancestors. 10 As in this
world a parent is not tied to the actions of his children, so in the
next world he is not tied to the results of their actions. 11 This
principle is illustrated by the following fact. 12 This creation is
the work of Praja¯pati and the seers. 13 We see the bodies of those
seers who have done meritorious deeds shining brilliantly far above.*
Dharma Sutras of Apasthambha 2.24.8-13


https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61460/does-self-imposed-conditional-promises-affect can u pls answer this question sir . It will be a great help .thanks

can you please answer this question sir https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61491/whatever-mentioned-in-purans-is-it-literally-correct-or-they-are-symbolical-trut

Is Dharma Sutras of Apasthambha authentic ? Is it part of Vedas ? Can you please share the link or reference in dharma sutras where regarding vows and promises is mentioned. Please share the source where you found with reference links. Thanks

Dharmasutras of Apasthambha is authentic .. search about it on Google. @Karthik

Is there anything mentioned about self imposed vows or promises . Fir example. If i do this, something bad happens to my family. Just an example. Like this regarding self imposed vows or promises is there anything mentioned. Could you please let me know. Many thanks

I request for some help sir I'm extremely worried because I am suffering with serious mental health issues. I keep making self imposed promises because I'm mentally unstable . For example if I eat junk food, let my father get adhogati. Like that i put promises to god dieties tulsi etc Is there any such rule or law or anything . Can you please let me know sir. Apologies if my question seems silly or absurd . But this is a big problem I'm facing . Please do help me out if possible if you can let me know if there is anything mentioned about such in scriptures. Would be very greatful

If you have broken a promise made to a particular deity then the best remedy IMO is to pray to that deity and ask for forgiveness on a daily basis  @Karthik

I) Your first question Please kindly answer my question by providing adequate scriptural references and kindly answer my question. Is there any rule in Hinduism or sanatana dharma.............will my father get ADHOGATI and never get human life because of me if i break the promise even if he has not done such huge bad karma in order to rot in animal lives for eternity and never get human life.
In Mahabharata [Adhi Parva Ch-8], Drupada and Drona were classmates who were so close and Drupada promised he would give half of the kingdom when he would become king. Drona was too poor to feed even his son, so he approached Drupada asking for a cow instead of half-kingdom but Drupada not only refused him but also insulted him. Unhappy Drona taught the Astra Vidya to Pandavas and subsequently, on the instructions of Drona, Arjuna defeated Drupada in the battle and brought him before Drona. However, Drona demonstrated his magnanimity and forgave him!
Bear in mind, Drupada was punished in the same birth for the breach of
promise and Mahabharata had never mentioned about his father, Prishata (aka Yajnasena) or lineage being suffered in hell or reached Adhigati because of broken promise!
II) Your second question I am suffering with severe mental health issues such as OCD (Obsessive compulsive disorder), Bipolar, Schizophrenia and on medical treatment…………………I do not put these promises intentionally or consciously.
You have mentioned about OCD (Obsessive compulsive disorder) and the treatment you are undergoing.
I pray Goddess Durga Parameshwari to bless you for your speedy
recovery.
III) Your third and final question So in short, My question is, is there any rule in scriptures that if we put a conditional promise (promise with a condition) that if i break this promise something bad happens to my loved ones, conditional promise. As I told in above examples . If I put a self imposed conditional promise and break it , what I had put in condition will it affect my family?
Padma Purana [Brahma-Kānda, chapter-26, slokas: 1-42] talks about the Importance of Keeping Promise. Its is conversation between Rishi Sūta
and Rishi Śaunaka. Rishi Sūta says what would happen if a promise offered using one's right hand is not kept up:

He goes to a terrible hell.
His dead ancestors are tormented in hell.

Rishi Sūta opens up a story in which a śūdra named Vīravikrama offered his daughter to brahmana Kṛṣṇaśarman. Despite his kinsmen opposition, Vīravikrama goes ahead with the offer by saying that I promised to offer my daughter to the brahmana with my right hand and I won't change my mind and I have to uphold it. Thus he kept up his word.
Holding a conch, a disc and a mace, mounted upon Garuḍa, Bhagavan Vishnu suddenly came there. After blessing  Vīravikrama for being kept up the promise, Bhagavan took the entire family of Vīravikrama to Vaikuṇṭha by a Vimāna (Aeroplane).
From your post, it is understood that you have never offered such a promise to a third person. All your vows are self-made, centering around you and no harm meant to others. So, You need not worry about your family being affected considering the nature of your promise.
Moreover, Padma Purana talks about dead ancestors who would suffer in hell. My question is what if your ancestors have taken punarjanma(reincarnation), then who else will rot in hell if you break a promise?
Similarly, I have very clearly answered in the first question that anybody's broken promises will never affect his lineage quoting an instance of Drupada-Drona incident that took place in Mahabharata. i.e. Drupada's broken promise never affected his lineage and Mahabharata never said so.
Conclusion:
Therefore, your broken promises are no way going to affect your parents
and their individual karma.
Update:
Another scriptural reference Vishnu Puranam: Book-2, Ch-6, sloka-25 says The violator of a vow, and one who breaks the rules of his order, falls into the Sandansa (or hell of pincers). Observe that unlike Padma Purana [Brahma-Kānda, chapter-26, slokas: 1-42], Vishnu Purana talks about neither ancestors nor parents but only about the violator! That is, break of a vow only affects the violator and nobody else.
Good Luck!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Padma Purana says that if you make a promise in front of deity or preceptor or fire or offering your right hand and break it or make a false promise offering your right hand then your ancestors will go to hell. But, in this case, you have not made any promise to anyone. Everything is in your mind.
Padma Purana IV.26.3-13

One should take an oath truthfully in the vicinity of a deity, fire, or one's preceptor.


O best sage, he who touches the flowers taken off after Vishnu's worship and takes a truthful oath (but does not keep it), is roasted, taking with him seven members (of his family), in hell for a long time.


What can be said about (what would happen) due to a false oath? The man who offer his right hand (to give a promise) and keeps it, would obtain Krishna. I am telling the truth, (and) the truth (only). The dead ancestors of him who, having offered his hand (to make a promise), does not keep it, are tormented in hell; and undoubtedly the dead one (i.e. he, after death) goes to a terrible
hell.


Can you please kindly answer this question sir https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61460/does-self-imposed-conditional-promises-affect

Also, one more question i had . Is everything mentioned in Purans meant to be literally taken and real working laws of nature or they are just mentioned in symbolic metaphorical way to highlight the importance. For example they say if u make a false oath u will be rotten in hell for 100 Manvantaras. I'm generally asking whatever mentioned in Purans are of them literal or just symbolically mentioned in puran so that people realise the importance of it ?? Because there are many things written in puran which are extremely huge punishments which is shocking

@Karthik If you do not upvote and accept the answer despite being useful (as I can understand from your request), why would I?

I have upvoted sir . Thanks for ur response . Please kindly answer this sir https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61460/does-self-imposed-conditional-promises-affect Thank you

Hello sir @Amritendu Mukhopadhyay https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61460/does-self-imposed-conditional-promises-affect pls kindly answer this question i have created a bounty sir

@Karthik I checked. But don't know the answer.

Sir one question I have. Suppose if someone breaks a oath , if their 7 generation ancestors were highly pious people and not done such huge sin to rot in hell for equally long period of time is it true because it cannot be applied in General right? If they were highly pious people and not done such huge sin to rot in hell, it will be against the Cosmic order of Dharma and Justice. If nirdoshi people have to suffer even if they haven't done such huge paap to deserve , it is against dharma and laws of god can be called unfair ?but god is not unfair. So what told in puran is it completely real ?

Suppose one ancestor may have done huge paap other ancestor may not have done huge paap some ancestors may have done lot of punya .so their paap and punya is not same ..but still all of them will rot in hell for equally long period of time if their descendants break a oath? What they have mentioned in puran is it really true ? If it is, it violates the cosmic order of Dharma and universal justice . Krishna clearly says I'm not partial and equal to everyone . So what they written in puran is it literally true in general sense?

My question is, is there any rule in scriptures that if we put a conditional promise (promise with a condition) that if i break this promise something bad happens to my loved ones, conditional promise. As I told in above examples . If I put a self imposed conditional promise and break it , what I had put in condition will it affect my family?
I am sorry to hear that you have mental issues.
Hindu scripture is meant for people who are healthy both in body and mind. In your case your strange promises are clearly due to the nature of your mind.

In regard to all beings in this world, the sovereign soul is not the
cause of the sense of agency, nor of actions, nor of the fruition of
actions. It is Nature that does all this.

Gita 5.14
Since you are not in control of your mind you can't be held responsible for your promises. Moreover there is something special about Kali Yoga.

Parikshit, who was like a honey-bee in grasping the essential good in
everything, abstained from killing Kali, because there is one great
excellence pertaining to his age – whatever good you do fructifies
immediately, but not so the evil deeds; and besides, in Kali’s age sin
accrues only to sinful deeds and not to sinful thoughts. Kali is like
one who is cowardly before the brave, but brave before the cowardly.
He holds no fear for the good, but like a wolf he is always vigilant
and alert to pounce upon those who are thoughtless and unobservant.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana translated by Swami Tapasyananda I.18.7
In kali Yuga sinful thoughts don't lead to anything bad. Only your deeds matter. Your parents are perfectly safe. You don't have to worry about them.

Okay sir. I have one doubt. Some say God doesn't interfere in karma phala everything happens automatically according to law of karma etc but some say Ishvara is dispenser of karma phala and god is just the witness . This is contradictory to each other

Buddhists and Jains say that everything happens automatically according to the law of Karma. Vedanta rejects that position and says that Isvara gives the fruits of Karma. It is that Atman in the Jiva which is the witness. You can think of God as Isvara the creator, preserver and destroyer of the universe and also as the Atman in the Jiva. There is no contradiction.

In 9.22.  krishna says those who always thinking of me he will take care of their necessities
Here in ,9.31 he says na mei bhakta pranshyati ..his devotees never perishes
Krishna does not mention " ananyaschintyanto " in this sloka..
ananyaschintyanto Krishna mentions in BG 9.22
So just wanted to ask does 9.31 Na mei bhakta pranshyati ( his devotee never perishes) only applies to " ananyaschintyanto (those who think of god always)" who are advanced devotees  ??. Or does it apply to any normal devotee also who worships God does chanting etc??)

It applies to advanced devotees who have made some progress in purifying their minds.

Sir one question I have. Suppose if someone breaks a oath , if their 7 generation ancestors were highly pious people and not done such huge sin to rot in hell for equally long period of time is it true because it cannot be applied in General right? If they were highly pious people and not done such huge sin to rot in hell, it will be against the Cosmic order of Dharma and Justice. If nirdoshi people have to suffer even if they haven't done such huge paap to deserve , it is against dharma and laws of god can be called unfair ?but god is not unfair. So what told in puran is it completely real ?

Suppose one ancestor may have done huge paap other ancestor may not have done huge paap some ancestors may have done lot of punya .so their paap and punya is not same ..but still all of them will rot in hell for equally long period of time if their descendants break a oath? What they have mentioned in puran is it really true ? If it is, it violates the cosmic order of Dharma and universal justice . Krishna clearly says I'm not partial and equal to everyone . So what they written in puran is it literally true in general sense?

Innocent people will not suffer is the bottom line.

Sir can you please answer this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61491/whatever-mentioned-in-purans-is-it-literally-correct-or-they-are-symbolical-trut
