Bhagavad Gita - 3 modes ( Satthva, Tamas, Rajas)
I have one question regarding Bhagavad Gita

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 14, Verse 14-15
यदा सत्त्वे प्रवृद्धे तु प्रलयं याति देहभृत् | तदोत्तमविदां
लोकानमलान्प्रतिपद्यते || 14|| रजसि प्रलयं गत्वा कर्मसङ्गिषु जायते |
तथा प्रलीनस्तमसि मूढयोनिषु जायते || 15||
BG 14.14-15: Those who die with predominance of sattva reach the pure
abodes (which are free from rajas and tamas) of the learned. Those who
die with prevalence of the mode of passion are born among people
driven by work, while those dying in the mode of ignorance take birth
in the animal kingdom.

It says the prevalence of satthva, or Rajas or Tamas decides the destination of the soul after death immediate next birth
And there is one more sloka which says,

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 14, Verse 18
ऊर्ध्वं गच्छन्ति सत्त्वस्था मध्ये तिष्ठन्ति राजसा: |
जघन्यगुणवृत्तिस्था अधो गच्छन्ति तामसा: || 18||
Translation 1(Swami Mukundananda)
BG 14.18: Those situated in the mode of goodness rise upward; those in
the mode of passion stay in the middle; and those in the mode of
ignorance go downward.
Translation 2( Srila Prabhupada)
Those situated in the mode of goodness gradually go upward to the
higher planets; those in the mode of passion live on the earthly
planets; and those in the abominable mode of ignorance go down to the
hellish worlds.

So sloka 14-15 is about what destination soul will go towards after death
Sloka 14.18 is also about same . So as it's same is it a duplicate? . Otherwise does it have a seperate meaning although the slokas translated meaning is same ?
Could it be possible that sloka 14-15 is talking about destination of soul after death based on its gunas of satthva Rajas Tamas ?
And sloka 18 is talking in general how does the soul move across lifetimes based on the 3 gunas based on the gunas in its karana shareer (causal body )?

Lord Krishna explains the same truth in different angles and puts forward accordingly because Arjuna was very confused and he had to be clarified.
By comparing both slokas, we arrive at Satva(सत्व) is goodness, Rajas(रजस्) is passion and Tamas(तमस्) is ignorance.

Therefore, the gist of Bhagavad Gita [Ch-14, Verses: 14-15] and
Bhagavad Gita [Ch-14, Verses: 18] is one and the same.

Your question is Could it be possible that sloka 14-15 is talking about destination of soul after death based on its gunas of satthva Rajas Tamas ? And sloka 18 is talking in general how does the soul move across lifetimes based on the 3 gunas based on the gunas in its karana shareer (causal body )?
When the heart predominates with one of three gunas at the time of death the punarjanma takes place accordingly as given below:

With predominance of Satva Guna, the Jīva reaches higher abodes or elevated birth such as Devas.
With predominance of Rajo Guna, the Jīva reborn as human.
With predominance of Tamo guna, the Jīva reaches lower regions such as animal kingdom as punarjanma.

The same above truth can also be expressed in parlance with Yoga Sutras in terms of samskāras(संस्कार/Latent Impressions). Kārana Sarīra(कारण शरीर/Causal Body) contains the cumulative collection of samskāras of all past incarnations. A subset of samskāras, which is ripe and going to sprout, will decide the nature of forthcoming birth. That subset is called Karmāsaya(कर्माशय/Latent Impressions of Action) responsible for Punarjanma(पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation).
Beware-1: In Vedānta parlance, Karmāsaya is known as Prārabdha Karma(प्रारब्ध कर्म/begun/commenced).
Beware-2: The Svetāsvatara upanishad (श्वेताश्वतर उपनिषद्) says the Supreme Purusha is in this body as Witness:

एको देवः सर्वभूतेषु गूढःसर्वव्यापी सर्वभूतान्तरात्मा।
कर्माध्यक्षः सर्वभूताधिवासःसाक्षी चेता केवलो निर्गुणश्च ॥ ६:११॥
eko devaḥ sarvabhūteṣu gūḍhaḥ sarvavyāpī sarvabhūtāntarātmā
karmādhyakṣaḥ sarvabhūtādhivāsaḥ **sākṣī **cetā kevalo nirguṇaś ca ॥ 6.11 ॥
The non-dual and resplendent Lord is hidden in all beings. All-pervading, the inmost Self of all creatures, the impeller to actions, abiding in all things, He is the Witness [Sākṣī], the Animator and the Absolute, free from gunas.

Bhagvad Gita corroborates Svetāsvatara upanishad that God is witness as follows [13.23]:

उपद्रष्टानुमन्ता च भर्ता भोक्ता महेश्वर: |
परमात्मेति चाप्युक्तो देहेऽस्मिन्पुरुष: पर: || 23||
upadrashtaanumantaa cha bhartaa bhoktaa maheshwarah
paramaatmeti chaapyukto dehe'smin purushah parah ॥ 13.23 ॥
The Supreme Purusha in this body is also called the Witness [upadraṣhṭā], the Approver, the Supporter, the Experiencer, the Sovereign Lord and the Supreme Self.

God will never favour this nor that, so God stands always without prejudice. To support this view more concretely, there is saying in Tamil:

அரசன் அன்று கொல்வான், தெய்வம் நின்று கொல்லும்.
Arasan andru kolvaan, Deivam Nindru Kollum.
Meaning: King will decide the death [punishment] on the same day and may be instantly but God will give long rope to teach us [through Karma] the lesson.

Conclusion:
Since Svetāsvatara Upanishad [6.11] and Bhagvad Gita [13.23] have been saying God is Witness [Sākṣī], therefore, Lord Krishna is witness. By saying Karmāsaya decides punarjanma is equivalent of saying Lord Krishna makes punarjanma decision according to Karmāsaya [or Prārabdha Karma in Vedānta parlance]. And there is no contradiction!

Yes Krishna is witness as mentioned in the Upanishads and Gita but at same time in BG 16.19 ,Krishna says I hurl the souls of demonic character into demonic wombs . Means he is deciding the next birth of such demonic people. So could it be possible that krishna is witness but as saguna brahman , karma-phala dhata or dispenser of fruits of action and decides next birth based on karma and Sanskaras ? So karmasaya deciding next birth and krishna deciding next birth based on karma is same but could there be possibility as per BG 16.19 that krishna is deciding the next birth based on our karma ?

It's also mentioned in Srimad bhagvatham that punarjanma takes place based on karma (in this case karmasaya) and under the supervision of the supreme Lord . (SB canto 3 chapter 31 )

@Karthik, you said "Means he is deciding the next birth of such demonic people". How does Krishna decide so?

From this sloka in BG 16.19, Krishna says he hurls those with demonic qualities into demonic wombs such as lower species . He takes the decision based on the Gunas(in this case Tamas as they are demonic or asuri souls) , and based on their bad karma . So if Krishna decides the next birth of demonic people, could it be inferred that Krishna decides the next birth of every soul . And that decision is taken based on the karma and the Samskaras or gunas

@Karthik, what do you mean by the statement "by under supervision of Supreme Lord"?

https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/31/1/ please kindly refer the commentary of SB 3.31.1 . It's mentioned  "karmana daiva netrena" as per the karma and under the supervision of supreme lord. It's mentioned that material nature supplies the body and everything takes place based on the Jiva's Karma and under the supervision of Lord. Means here God is making sure or supervising this process or overseeing to make sure the jiva gets the type of body he deserves based on its karma and Samskaras ?

@Karthik, if Krishna decides the next birth of every soul, then what is difference between Hinduism and Abrahamic religions(Judaism, Christianity, and Islam)? i.e. Krishna is prejudiced tantamount to Abrahamic Gods! Are you sure about that?

No sir Krishna is never prejudiced because  he says in Bhagavad Gita that he is equal towards all living beings and if Krishna takes the decision , he does only according to the Karma and the Samskaras alone. So even if Krishna decides the Jiva deserves what it has to get based on its karma alone . So the jiva gets the type of body and the prarabdha as it deserves and the decision happens as per the karma alone and there is no prejudice as Krishna says he is never partial to anyone and he is equal to every living entity . Please correct me if am wrong

Good, you have more or less reached the point. Go for deeper study of Vedānta Darshana and Yoga Darshana in order to sharpen your mind further. Always remember BG[18.63] wherein Lord Krishna says  “Thus, I have explained to you this knowledge that is more secret than all secrets. Ponder over it deeply, and then do as you wish”. This implies that Krishna is calling Arjuna’s attention to his free will and asking him to choose. The message conveyed is Just because I am God, don’t accept my words blindly! I Hope you may close this conversation with this. Good Luck!

Thanks . I just need one help sir. Regarding the breaking promises question, I just wanted to ask something.I have  modified that question and updated . Can u pls have a look and answer me . Just one last thing I needed a help. It would be very helpful I would be very greatful . Please kindly do the needful . Thanks . https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61359/breaking-promises-do-our-loved-ones-ancestors-rot-in-hell-and-or-suffer-if-we-b . Thanks

@Karthik it is done. Good Luck!

Thanks a lot sir. I just had a query related to a sloka in BG. I request if you can please answer this. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61408/can-bg-9-31-slokam-be-disproved-that-it-is-non-functional Thanks
