Can BG 9.31 slokam which states "Naa mei bhakta pranshyati" be disproved that it is non functional?
Please Note :- This is not duplicate but related to this
As per BG 9.31,

BHAGAVAD GITA CHAPTER 9 VERSE 31
Bg. 9.31 क्षिप्रं भवति धर्मात्मा शश्वच्छान्तिं निगच्छति । कौन्तेय
प्रतिजानीहि न मे भक्त: प्रणश्यति ॥ ३१ ॥
He quickly becomes righteous and attains lasting peace. O
son of Kuntī, declare it boldly that My devotee never perishes.

Here, let us assume perish means a Jiva rotting in lower Yonis for eternity never getting a human life for eternity as long as God exists ?( When I say as long as God exists I mean to convey that the jiva is perishing and never able to get human birth for eternity)
As per above sloka, Krishna says his devotees never perish
My question is, let us consider two scenarios of devotees who are Mukti yogya and sadhana siddha ( who are eligible for moksha)
Case 1. Devotee has done huge sins . In this case could there be possibility that he can never get human life again and perish for eternity ?
Case 2. If someone curse the devotee that let him never get human life and perish for eternity he would perish for eternity?.
So in above 2 cases, the devotee is perishing and never get human birth again. So that means his spritual progress is halted and because of the fact that he never gets human birth again his chances of moksha and further spiritual advancement is lost. So it's against the sloka where krishna says his devotees never perish.
Also for this question let us assume that this devotee is not a Yogi. So the concept of brasht Yogi (BG 6.41) doesn't apply either as that is only for Brahstha yogis
So from this can we prove that This slokam (BG 9.31) is disproved and non-functional as devotees are perishing which contradicts and negates Krishna's Statement (or assurance)?
So does it disprove this sloka and prove that it does not apply to any devotee in real life ?
Or is there any way this verse can be disproved?
Please kindly clarify it
Thanks

Actually you should read about jada-bharat 's sadhana in deer yoni and you should also hear gajendra moksha katha from srimad Bhagvatam it is impossible for a sincere devotee to not cross the maya some even cross yog maya

Short Answer:
Firstly, none of the verses in our scriptures such as the Bhagavad Gita are non-functional. They only need to be understood correctly.
A sadhana-siddha or a jivana-mukta will never commit sins in the first place or become affected by his previous sins as he's acting on the platform of the self or the spirit soul being fully surrendered to the Supreme Lord. Also, no one has the capacity to inflict a curse on such a liberated being due to his elevated state of consciousness.
Long Answer:
All previous karmas of anyone who simply surrenders to Lord Krishna are nullified personally by Lord Krishna Himself (ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo) than what to speak of a sadhana-siddha.
सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज ।
अहं त्वां सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा श‍ुच: ॥ ६६ ॥


Abandon all varieties of religion and just surrender unto Me. I shall
deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.

One cannot curse a liberated soul. Such a so-called curse would be reversed and destroy the originator and would considered as an aparadha or an offense. An example of this is given in the Bhagavata Purana 9.4 where Durvasa Muni tries punish King Ambarisha who was a great devotee of Lord Krishna but gets countered by the Lord's sudarshana-chakra.

अजानता ते परमानुभावं
कृतं मयाघं भवत: प्रियाणाम् ।

O my Lord, O supreme controller, without knowledge of Your unlimited
prowess I have offended Your most dear devotee. Very kindly save me
from the reaction of this offense. You can do everything, for even if
a person is fit for going to hell, You can deliver him simply by
awakening within his heart the holy name of Your Lordship.

Even for a devotee who is not mukti-yogya yet and may be falling down due to his previous samskaras, he does not suffer indefinitely in the animal species of life as asserted by Lord Krishna. Also, any devotee who worships Krishna by chanting His Name does not go to hell then what to speak of one who is a sadhana-siddha. This is spoken by Durvasa Rishi.

विधेहि तस्यापचितिं विधात-
र्मुच्येत यन्नाम्न्युदिते नारकोऽपि ॥ ६२ ॥

You can do everything, for even if a person is fit for going to hell,
You can deliver him simply by awakening within his heart the holy name
of Your Lordship.

Let's look at another example from Bhagavata Purana 5.8:
The devotee King Bharata became a deer due to his affection towards a deer at the the end of his life. This is an example of a fall-down but it was not a permanent one as per the promise of Krishna in the Gita. In his subsequent life, King Bharata who was now a deer becomes a Brahmana devotee known as Jada-Bharata (externally appearing dull) due to his internal meditative trance on Krishna.
He was very soon (kṣipraṁ) cleansed of his past actions and became a fully liberated righteous soul (bhavati dharmātmā).
One who constantly thinks of Lord Krishna (bhajate yo māṁ) with unflinching faith (śraddhāvān) is considered the greatest of the Yogis as per the Gita.

योगिनामपि सर्वेषां मद्ग‍तेनान्तरात्मना ।
श्रद्धावान्भजते यो मां स मे युक्ततमो मत: ॥ ४७ ॥

And of all yogīs, the one with great faith who always abides in Me,
thinks of Me within himself and renders transcendental loving service
to Me – he is the most intimately united with Me in yoga and is the
highest of all. That is My opinion.


Thanks for the answer. Just small correction in my case he is not jivan-mukta . He is only sadhana-siddha (as per srila Prabhupada) for a devotee who is doing sadhana . If he was jivan-mukta as you said curse cannot be applicable. That's a seperate case . Here, in this case for this question we are assuming the case that he is a sincere devotee of Ishvara and doing sadhana such as Puja (worshipping God) nam jap chanting parayan etc . My question is suppose if someone curse such a person to never get human life and rot in adho-yoni for eternity, can god protect him from such a curse ?

my pleasure. Isn't a sadhana-siddha a liberated soul? Siddha means liberated.

No sir . Actually this is a term created by Srila Prabhupada He classifies souls into 3 categories , Nithya-badda, Nithya-siddha and sadhana-siddha. Nithya badda can never get moksha . And nithya-siddha is a liberated soul. Sadhana-siddha is for a normal devotee who is at intermediate stage between Nithya badda and Nithya siddha. So sadhana siddha is not liberated soul as per Srila Prabhupada. My question is suppose if someone curse a devotee to never get human life and rot in adho-yoni for eternity, can god protect him from such a curse ?(If he has not done bad karma to deserve it )

Would be very greatful if you can kindly update or edit your answer for this case. Sorry to bother you Thanks in advance.

Yes absolutely, a curse would not still not apply as the Name of Krishna which is essentially a Namatmaka Mantra will counter it. He should be careful to not deliberately commits sins on the strength of the name as it'd cause rebirth for many millions of lives as the Deity of the Mantra will be offended by such behavior. If he's sincere and repents for any mistakes, He'll be personally taken care from his previous karmas as well as any curses.

Sadhana-siddha is one has become Siddha by the strength of his own sadhana but was previously conditioned. See here: https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Sadhana-siddha

But there are also others, who may not be liberated from birth but who develop a tendency for devotional service by association, and they are called sādhana-siddhas. (Source: Link)

responded in chat sir. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/156501/discussion-between-karthik-and-harihara

Can you please respond in chat sir. I have asked a question. Thanks

Done. You can search for verses about the glories of the holy name of Krishna for more info.

I) Your first question Here, let us assume perish means a Jiva rotting in lower Yonis for eternity never getting a human life for eternity as long as God exists ?( When I say as long as God exists I mean to convey that the jiva is perishing and never able to get human birth for eternity)
Yes, you are right.
II) Your second question As per above sloka, Krishna says his devotees never perish.
This is what Lord Krishna guarantees His devotees! Why? Sincere and true devotees earns virtues through Krishna Bhakti, however ends up adhogati (lower births) after their death due to bad Sanchita karma. Lord Krishna guarantees that in some future birth, the samskāras (संस्कार/Latent Impressions) corresponding to Krishna Bhakti would ripe and sprout into human birth. As per BG [8.6], the Jiva will continue Krishna Bhakti from that state. Bear in mind that as per Svetāsvatara upanishad [6.11] and BG [13.23], Krishna always stands as Witness!
III) Your third question My question is, let us consider two scenarios of devotees who are Mukti yogya and sadhana siddha ( who are eligible for moksha).
Yes, you are right.
IV) Your fourth question Case 1. Devotee has done huge sins . In this case could there be possibility that he can never get human life again and perish for eternity?
You should qualify huge sin. Do you mean past karma? Assume that Jiva’s has accumulated bad karmas in the past incarnations.  Due to his past actions, he may take plenty of low grade births however Jiva was basically Mukti yogi (or Sadhana Siddha), so that Jiva should have accumulated enough punya samskāras which will cause a human birth! Therefore perishing for eternity is fallacious.
V) Your fifth question Case 2. If someone curse the devotee that let him never get human life and perish for eternity he would perish for eternity?
You have already set the premises such as Jiva is either a Mukti yogya or Sadhana Siddha. So, there is no way for such curse because Jiva has already accumulated punya in this birth. Those samskāras will definitely earn him either modification of curse or Śāpa-Vimocana through some higher force.
VI) Your sixth question So in above 2 cases, the devotee is perishing and never get human birth again. So that means his spritual progress is halted and because of the fact that he never gets human birth again his chances of moksha and further spiritual advancement is lost. So it's against the sloka where krishna says his devotees never perish.
Please refer answers for questions IV and V.
VII) Your seventh question Also for this question let us assume that this devotee is not a Yogi. So the concept of brasht Yogi (BG 6.41) doesn't apply either as that is only for Brahstha yogis.
Yoga-bhraṣṭa(योगभ्रष्ट) means one who falls down from the path of spiritual advancement. After death, they usually reach higher abodes(such as Deva Loka, Satya Loga, Vaigunta and Kailāsa) and live there for very very long time before taking human incarnation again. In yoga parlance they are called Videha(विदेह/விதேகர்/The Bodiless) and Prakriti-laya(प्रकृतिलय/ப்ரக்ருதிலயர்/Those who dissolved in Prakriti) respectively who possess powers more or less on par with Gods!
If Jiva is not a yogi and his samskāras in causal body are not enough to fetch him a human incarnation, then he will suffer for ever. In order this to happens, Jivas should have committed only cruel/wicked acts throughout, without an iota of viruous acts, not only in this life but also in all of their human births so far assumed! That is why Madvāchārya calls them as Nitya-samsārins and Tamo-yogyas who are denied moksha. Please understand clearly that this a very very rare scenario and highly improbable to occur!
VIII) Your eighth question So from this can we prove that This slokam (BG 9.31) is disproved and non-functional as devotees are perishing which contradicts and negates Krishna's Statement (or assurance)? So does it disprove this sloka and prove that it does not apply to any devotee in real life.
Lord Krishna’s upadesa of Bhagavath Geeta will always be true and never go wrong because His words are the essence of knowledge of Veda, Upanishads and Shad Darshana! The true Krishna devotees always will get an opportunity to assume a human form even after suffering crores and crores of lower births due to their Sanchita Karma.

In BG [15.15] Krishna says: I am seated in the hearts of all living
beings, and from Me come memory, knowledge, as well as forgetfulness.
I alone am to be known by all the Vedas, am the author of the Vedanta,
and the knower of the meaning of the Vedas.

IX) Your ninth and final question Or is there any way this verse can be disproved?
No way, your contention is fallacious.
Good Luck!

Thank you very much..Just a small clarification, if there is a sincere devotee of God and worships Ishvara, parayanam, Naam jap chanting and follow the principles of Bhakti Yoga. Is he also come under sadhana-siddha or mukti -yogya? Whatever you mentioned does this apply on such a person?

And in Question no. 5, you mentioned if in case the Jiva is Mukti-yogya and sadhana-siddha if jiva has done enough punya and samsakaras can God modify or provide shaap-vimochan and save from eternal damnation or perishing? Does it apply on such a person sir? Can god protect such a person from curse and grant shaap-vimochan even if he has done Huge Paap (sin) and got such curse ? Or does he eternally perish because of that curse. Even if someone has done huge paap and got such curse , by punya from sadhana and bhakti marg can god modify the curse forgive his paap and save from spiritual perish?

Answer to your first comment: The Jiva who is born as a human, should have already committed enough Punya Karma (in the past human incarnations) which resulted the present human birth. As per BG [8.6], the Jiva will continue from that state onwards, now worshiping Ishvara, conducting prāyānāmam, performing Naama japa and following the principles of Bhakti Yoga. Jiva should carry on this momentum not only in the present human form but also in future human incarnation too in order to keep qualifying for mukti-yogya/sadhana-siddha. This is not one birth process but continuity.

There are basically two questions in your latest comment. Your first question: you mentioned if in case the Jiva is Mukti-yogya and sadhana-siddha ……..or perishing? Does it apply on such a person sir? True, but if his past karmas are too bad, Jiva may have to assume crores of lower births before assuming a human incarnation again. Thus, such Jiva always gets opportunities for human incarnation in continuity in order to redeem. Apart from indulging in wicked acts, Jiva should at least commit some punya karma in every human incarnation in order to maintain that continuity.

Your 2nd question: Can god protect……from spiritual perish? Jiva, who suffers eternal damnation, should have zero punya karma in his stock of Sanchita karma. Is such state possible? That is why Madvāchārya’s Tatva of Nitya-samsārins and Tamo-yogyas are improbable. Jiva, in his human form, indulges in all kinds of cruel acts but he would have definitely committed at least one or two punya karmas unknowingly! Those are enough to fetch him a human incarnation again even after a continuity of crores and crores of lower incarnations. So, eternal curse is highly improbable!

Thanks lot. I just had one small doubt sir . I just wanted to clarify one point In this sloka Krishna says न मे भक्त: प्रणश्यति
My question is , is the validity of this sloka based on Krishna's active interference  and protection? Because Krishna is just witness as you mentioned from upanishads . So in order to keep up the validity of this sloka, does krishna need to actively intervene and protect every devotee from perishing
OR
This is an independent rule created by God where the laws of karma automatically make sure his devotees are not perished?

@Karthik , Despite involving in wicked acts, as a Krishna Bhakta had he committed punya karma, those punya samskāras are enough to fetch him another human embodiment after his body falls (may not be immediate, but even after cores of lower incarnations that depends on Sanchita Karma). This is what Krishna means न मे भक्त: प्रणश्यति. This does not violate Lord Krishna being Witness! Always remember Lord Krishna will never go against Law of karma, otherwise He will be accused of prejudice.

Thanks sir Got it . But actually my question was a little different. Does krishna need to actively intervene and protect his devotees from spiritual perishing in order to keep up this promise or validity of this slokam? Basically, my question is does God intervenes and need to protect his devotee from perishing if in case a situation comes where devotee is bound to perish ? (Is God intervention required to protect devotees from perishing) OR This is an independent rule created by God where the laws of karma automatically make sure his devotees are not perished based on this sloka?

Karma takes care! In this sloka of BG [9.31], the interpretation is that Krishna speaks through karma alone. If Lord Krishna overrides Karma, then there is no difference between Him and Abrahmic Gods who are prejudiced because they threaten their followers to obey the rules and they are prejudiced enough to cause Jiva who is born as a boy or a girl, who is born rich or poor, who is born blind or not, who is born deaf or not, who is born dump or not, who is born brilliant or dull or insane and so on, without logic.

Okay so if i understood you correctly, that means that this promise or assurance or statement which Krishna has mentioned Na mei bhakta pranshyati  is a part of law of karma itself , in other words law of karma itself is designed in such a way that sincere devotees of god does not perish to uphold the validity of this slokam told by krishna ? Please let me know if my understanding is correct. So this is a working  principle created by krishna that his devotee never perish designed as part of law of karma itself ?

Sorry to bother you sir . Please kindly let me know if this understanding is correct ? Just a last thing wanted to ask regarding this topic. Just to double check if this understanding is correct or not. Thanks

There is no such logic called Part of Karma or Part of God but wholly it is the law of karma alone! Law of karma works alone like God is Witness. If God says in Hinduism "I control you", implies that He controls all Jivas only through Karma otherwise He will be  accused of prejudice! If you commit punya then your punarjanma will be higher; if you commit pāpa, your reincarnation will be lower. If you nurture Krishna Bhakti truly, then it will fetch you stronger punya samskāras which will ensure a human birth again. This equivalent of saying न मे भक्त: प्रणश्यति.

Yes I meant to say same. So can we say this न मे भक्त: प्रणश्यति is a working principle created by God. And law of karma works as per this principle created by God? There are many factors based on which law of karma takes into consideration while deciding next birth . So can we say  Na mei bhakta pranshyati this is also a factor which law of karma works upon?

Wrong! Both are different angles of perceiving the same truth. If you express punarjanma in terms of Law of Karma or in terms of Bhagavan Krishna, both are one and the same! That means Lord Krishna always works through Law of Karma and never Indiscriminately!

I apologise if I'm bothering you sir . Thanks a lot for your time and efforts . Just this one last thing wanted to clarify with you. . Please kindly answer me .As you mentioned everything happens based on Law or karma only I totally got it sir . My question was a little different. If in case you didn't get my question clearly. In simple words , my question was Law of Karma works in such a way that devotees of Ishvara never perish (as mentioned by Krishna in BG 9.31 )?

@Karthik  Please Study Patanjali yoga sutras thoroughly, otherwise it is hard to  grasp the intricacies and inter-relationship among God, Law of Karma(Knowledge of Samskāra and Karmāsaya in parlance to yoga sutras) and Punarjanma(reincarnation). Without this knowledge, any amount of conversation between us will never yield fruits. Good Luck!

Okay sir sure I will surely go through them. Thanks for your inputs and guidance .Just one last thing wanted to ask based on one of your comments . In above comments you had mentioned that Karma takes  care! In this sloka of BG [9.31], the interpretation is that Krishna speaks through karma alone can you please clarify what exactly you meant by this ?  I just wanted to clarify myself. This will be my last question regarding this thread(or topic ) . I just wanted to know what did you mean by that . Please do answer this one last query.  Many Thanks
