Whatever mentioned in Purans is it literally correct or they are symbolical truths rather than literal truths?
I want to ask something. Is the punishments of hell rebirth etc or anything that is basically mentioned in Purans are literal truths or symbolically mentioned to convey certain message to people rather than literal truths ?
In Shiva Maha puran, Rudra Samhita,Sati Khanda , Chapter 43, Verses 16-17


He attains peace, who does not see any difference among the three deities who constitute the soul of all living beings and who have the
same innate property, O Dakṣa.

The base man who differentiates the deities of the Trinity certainly stays in hell as long as the moon and the stars shine



Also in Devi Bhagavtham, Book 9, Chapter 34

If anybody makes any difference (superiority or inferiority) between
his own Iṣta Deva (his Deity), his Spiritual Teacher, his natural
father, and mother, is certainly involved in the sin of Brahmahattyā
Whoever seeing his spiritual teacher, and a Brāhmaṇ, does not bow down
and make respectful obeisance to them, commits Gohattyā.
Those who eat without washing their feet or those who sleep with their
feet wetted with water and those who eat just after the Sun has risen,
commit Gohattyā.

Are they completely literal and applies literally to everyone such as many devotees are there in Kali Yuga who differentiate between Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva etc , does that mean they literally rot in hell as long as stars shine (till one Kalpa or extremely long period of time like eternity if I'm not wrong )?
Or
They may not be literal but symbolic truths to convey people the message that one should not differentiate between Gods
And also regarding Gohatya, if someone eats food without washing feet does they get Sin of killing a cow?
Again, here also is it literal truth or symbolic truths to convey people the message ?
Also, in many puran it's mentioned one who sincerely observes ekadasi are liberated? But liberation only comes to those who are self realised or great Yogis or Bhaktas of God . Just by performing one ekadasi they may not get liberated .

Whoever faithfully observes this Ekadashi fast, which is like
chinta-mani (a gem that yields all desires), obtains special merit
that is very hard to calculate, for this day can elevate one from
hellish life to the heavenly planets, and for one who observes
Ekadashi for his own spiritual benefit, this elevates one to go back
to Godhead, never to return to this material world."    Thus end the
narration of the glories of Margashirsha-shukla Ekadashi or Mokshada
Ekadashi, from the Brahmanda Purana.

So in a nutshell, All these whatever is mentioned in Purans are they literal truths or they are symbolic truths to convey people of Dharma and Adharma ?

All that is mentioned in the Puranas are literally true either in a physical sense or the metaphysical sense. It depends on the context when the truth about the physical world in mentioned and the truth about the metaphysical world is mentioned.
The verse 16-17 of Shiva Purana uses the term भेदबुद्धि: in which the भेद here refers to the सामदामदण्डभेद kind of भेद where you try to misrepresent the three Devatas and try to show one as superior and one as inferior. So in this sense the verses of Shiva Purana are correct.
Also, when it comes to the verse of Devi Bhagwatam the word is स्निग्धपादेन स्निग्धाङ्‌घ्रि which means oily feet/toes not wet feet/toes. And most of these injunctions actually are not applicable in आपत्काल or emergencies. We live in an era where Dharma is in decline which is an emergency situation so a lot of these injunctions are not going to be applicable. That is why in Mahabharata it is said that Dharma is very subtle. Also, in the Mahabharata it is mentioned that when you go to Yamaloka you are given a chance to explain your breachings of Dharma and if you can rationalize your breachings honestly Yamaraja will take away yours sins. Those you cannot rationalize honestly those sins will stay with you.
And liberation by Ekadashivrata is literally true. There is no second guessing there.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
